# Regex to get the string after @ sign

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like follows:

`@78517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec`, `@68517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec`, `@98517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec`, `@38517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec` ....

I want to extract the string after `@`.

I have the current code like follows:

```
private final static Pattern PATTERN_LOGIN = Pattern.compile("@[^\\s]+");
Matcher m = PATTERN_LOGIN.matcher("@78517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec , @68517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, @98517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec, @38517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec");
while (m.find()) {
        String mentionedLogin = m.group();
        .......
   }
```

... but `m.group()` gives me `@78517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec` but I wanted `78517700-1f01-11e3-a6b7-3c970e02b4ec`

Comment: You can simply use `@(.*)`

Comment: Read up on the use of brackets in regex's - the top answer will almost certainly use them, and they're useful to know for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the regex `"@([^\\s]+)"` and then `m.group(1)`, which returns you what "captured" by the capturing parentheses `()`.

`m.group()` or `m.group(0)` return you the full matching string found by your regex.

Answer (score 3):

I would modify the pattern to omit the at sign:

```
private final static Pattern PATTERN_LOGIN = Pattern.compile("@([^\\s]+)");
```

So the first group will be the GUID only

Answer (score 0):

Correct answers are mentioned in other responses. I will add some clarification. Your code is working correctly, as expected.

Your regex means: match string which starts with `@` and after that follows one or more characters which isn't white space. So if you omit the parentheses you get you full string as expected.

The parentheses as mentioned in other responses are used for marking capturing groups. In layman terms - the regex engine does the matching multiple times for each parenthesis enclosed group, working it's way inside the nested structure.